# Android, opencsv and writing to an assets file

Tags: android, csv, assets, opencsv

I can read from a csv file in the assets folder, using opencsv. However, writing to the file was a bit more mysterious.

I do the following to open up a file in the /assets folder for reading:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("shoppinglists.csv")));
```

How do I open the file for writing, and how to I do the writing? Using getAssets() for accessing the file seams clean, so I'd like to use it for reading also.

Comment: Sorry.. You can't. As android .apk file structure is **Read-Only**.. Better to use **Application's Internal Storage** or **External Storage**.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't write to the asset file as it is part of the APK.

If I were you, I would copy the asset file into your temp directory and write to that copy as required.

Comment: Ah, crap. I suspected that. But this is a file that's going to live with the application, so temo folder is a bad idea. Where is a good idea to keep a "database" file for the application?

Comment: In the data directory, see the Context class

Answer (score 0):

Assets folder is present in the packaged apk. It is read only. So you cannot write to it.

Comment: You can use [Context.getDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to get the directory where you can store your files. Or if it is temporary you could call [Context.getCacheDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29)